# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,1,1500) (1,512)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

For my project I am trying to compare between LSTM and GRU for video captioning. I started with an open source LSTM code. And after making changes for the GRU the model trains perfectly. But I am getting the mentioned value error when I am trying to test. So I am attaching the code of testing below

```
###Testing Block###
# class to perform inference on all test files and save as test_output.txt
class Video2Text(object):
    ''' Initialize the parameters for the model '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.latent_dim = 512
        self.num_encoder_tokens = 4096
        self.num_decoder_tokens = 1500
        self.time_steps_encoder = 80
        self.time_steps_decoder = None
        self.preload = True
        self.preload_data_path = 'preload_data'
        self.max_probability = -1

        # processed data
        self.encoder_input_data = []
        self.decoder_input_data = []
        self.decoder_target_data = []
        self.tokenizer = None

        # models
        self.encoder_model = None
        self.decoder_model = None
        self.inf_encoder_model = None
        self.inf_decoder_model = None
        self.save_model_path = 'model_final'
        self.test_path = 'testing_data'
    def load_inference_models(self):
        # load tokenizer
        
        with open(os.path.join(self.save_model_path, 'tokenizer' + str(self.num_decoder_tokens)), 'rb') as file:
            self.tokenizer = joblib.load(file)

        # inference encoder model
        self.inf_encoder_model = load_model(os.path.join(self.save_model_path, 'encoder_model.h5'))

        # inference decoder model
        decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, self.num_decoder_tokens))
        decoder_dense = Dense(self.num_decoder_tokens, activation='softmax')
        decoder_gru = GRU(self.latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
        decoder_state_input_h = Input(shape=(self.latent_dim,))
        decoder_state_input_c = Input(shape=(self.latent_dim,))
        #decoder_states_inputs = [decoder_state_input_h,decoder_state_input_c]
        decoder_state_input=[decoder_state_input_h]
        decoder_outputs, state_h = decoder_gru(decoder_inputs, initial_state=decoder_state_input_h)
        print(state_h.shape)
        decoder_states = [state_h]
        print(np.shape(decoder_states))
        decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)
        print(decoder_outputs.shape)
        self.inf_decoder_model = Model(
            [decoder_inputs] + decoder_state_input,
            [decoder_outputs] + decoder_states)
        self.inf_decoder_model.load_weights(os.path.join(self.save_model_path, 'decoder_model_weights.h5'))
    
    def decode_sequence2bs(self, input_seq):
        states_value = self.inf_encoder_model.predict(input_seq)
        #print(np.shape(states_value))
        target_seq = np.zeros((1, self.num_decoder_tokens))
        target_seq[0, self.tokenizer.word_index['bos']] = 1
        print(input_seq.shape)
        caption = self.greedy_search(input_seq)
        return caption


    def greedy_search(self, f):
        """
        :param f: the loaded numpy array after creating videos to frames and extracting features
        :return: the final sentence which has been predicted greedily
        """
        inv_map = self.index_to_word()
        states_value = self.inf_encoder_model.predict(f.reshape(-1, 80, 4096))
        print(states_value.shape)
        target_seq = np.zeros((1, 1500))
        final_sentence = ''
        target_seq[0, self.tokenizer.word_index['bos']] = 1
        print(target_seq.shape)
        for i in range(15):
            output_tokens, h = self.inf_decoder_model.predict([target_seq] + states_value)
            states_value = [h]
            output_tokens = output_tokens.reshape(self.num_decoder_tokens)
            y_hat = np.argmax(output_tokens)
            if y_hat == 0:
                continue
            if inv_map[y_hat] is None:
                break
            if inv_map[y_hat] == 'eos':
                break
            else:
                final_sentence = final_sentence + inv_map[y_hat] + ' '
                target_seq = np.zeros((1, 1500))
                target_seq[0, y_hat] = 1
        #print(final_sentence)
        return final_sentence

    def decoded_sentence_tuning(self, decoded_sentence):
        decode_str = []
        filter_string = ['bos', 'eos']
        unigram = {}
        last_string = ""
        for idx2, c in enumerate(decoded_sentence):
            if c in unigram:
                unigram[c] += 1
            else:
                unigram[c] = 1
            if(last_string == c and idx2 > 0):
                continue
            if c in filter_string:
                continue
            if len(c) > 0:
                decode_str.append(c)
            if idx2 > 0:
                last_string = c
        return decode_str
    
    def index_to_word(self):
        # inverts word tokenizer
        index_to_word = {value: key for key, value in self.tokenizer.word_index.items()}
        return index_to_word

    def get_test_data(self, path):
        X_test = []
        X_test_filename = []
        %cd /content/drive/My\ Drive/Video-Captioning-main/data/
        with open (os.path.join(path, 'testing_id.txt')) as testing_file:
            lines = testing_file.readlines()
            for filename in lines:
                filename = filename.strip()
                #print(filename)
                f = np.load(os.path.join(path , 'feat', filename + '.npy'))
                X_test.append(f)
                X_test_filename.append(filename[:-4])
            X_test = np.array(X_test)
            #print(f)
        return X_test, X_test_filename

    def test(self):
        X_test, X_test_filename = self.get_test_data(os.path.join(self.test_path))
        print(len(X_test), len(X_test_filename))
        # generate inference test outputs
        %cd /content/drive/My\ Drive/Video-Captioning-main/model_final/
        with open(os.path.join(self.save_model_path, 'test_output_greedy.txt'), 'w') as file:
            for idx, x in enumerate(X_test): 
                file.write(X_test_filename[idx]+',')
                decoded_sentence = self.decode_sequence2bs(x.reshape(-1, 80, 4096))
                #print(decoded_sentence)
                file.write(decoded_sentence + ' ')
                file.write('\n')
                # re-init max prob
                #self.max_probability = -1
```

And the code for building the GRU. In here you can see that encoder_gru outputs one state in addition to encoder_out. But in LSTM it provided 2 additional outputs. So I think this is finally causing the error. Because then in lstm I got (1,1,1500) and (2,1,512).

```
# Setting up the encoder
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(time_steps_encoder, num_encoder_tokens), name="encoder_inputs")
encoder_gru = GRU(latent_dim, return_state=True,return_sequences=True, name='endcoder_gru')
encoder_out, encoder_state = encoder_gru(encoder_inputs)

# Set up the decoder
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(time_steps_decoder, num_decoder_tokens), name= "decoder_inputs")
decoder_gru = GRU(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name='decoder_gru')
decoder_outputs, decoder_state = decoder_gru(decoder_inputs, initial_state=encoder_state)
decoder_dense = Dense(num_decoder_tokens, activation='softmax', name='decoder_relu')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)


model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
model.summary()
plot_model(model, to_file='model_train.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
```

And following is the exact line where I am getting the error:

```
<ipython-input-66-ebbb2fcfd630> in greedy_search(self, f)
     78         print(target_seq.shape)
     79         for i in range(15):
---> 80             output_tokens, h = self.inf_decoder_model.predict([target_seq] + states_value)
     81             states_value = [h]
     82             output_tokens = output_tokens.reshape(self.num_decoder_tokens)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,1,1500) (1,512)
```

In testing block I tried with making the shapes (1,1500) and (1,512), but even then it gives the same error.